# Regex across double line break

Tags: regex

I have the following text, and I need to extra parts out of it:

```
[Firstname LastName 21/06/2018 - 17:27]
Lorem Ipsum

[Foo Bar 25/01/2017 - 12:10]
Lorem Ipsum - First line
Lorem ipsum Second line
Lorem ipsum third line


Some other random text
```

I need to extract parts of this text, which I have almost managed to do using the following regex:

```
\[(?<name>\w+? \w+?) (?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) - (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2})\]\n*(?<note>.+)
```

Everything works correctly, except for the group labelled `<note>`, it's only picking up the first line of the note. If there is a line break in the note, then anything after the line break is not picked up.

How can I get it to match all text in the note section, until the regex finds a double line break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for `.` (which does not include newlines by default) you can look for `[^[]`, or every character before the next square bracket, followed by two line breaks:

```
\[(?<name>\w+? \w+?) (?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) - (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2})\]\n*(?<note>[^[]+\n\n)
```

https://regex101.com/r/12S3ZQ/3

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your original regex to give you the expected output.

```
\[(?<name>\w+? \w+?) (?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) - (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2})\]\n*(?<note>.+\n?\n?)+
```

It should match everything until the double line break, notice the only change is at the end.

Instead of...

`(?<note>.+)`

It is now...

`(?<note>.+\n?\n?)+`

Edit: Changed the regex so it will include lines separated by ONE line break, but not two.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
\[(?<name>\w+? \w+?) (?<date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}) - (?<time>\d{2}:\d{2})\]\s*(?<note>[\s\S]+?)(?=\n{2}|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rvWMKS/1)

The `(?<note>[\s\S]+?)(?=\n{2}|$)` will match 1+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first 2 newline chars or end of string.

If your regex engine supports `\R` construct to match any line break sequence, you can use `(?=\R{2}|$)`.